# Asyncio issues running an external command

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

I am looking to run an external command in an async coroutine (along with other coroutines). The intent is for other coroutines (run as tasks) continue running while this coro is blocked/executing the external command.
Here is my test code that runs two coroutines: I want to run both simultaneously, and print the output of the external command after it is run.

```
import asyncio

async def checker():
    for i in range(30):
        print(f'Checker Iteration: {i}')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def foo():
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec("speedtest", stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    await asyncio.gather(asyncio.to_thread(proc))
    print(f'Process Return Code: {proc.returncode} and Output: \n{proc.stdout}')

async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(checker())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(foo())
    await(t1)

        
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

But, when I run the above code, I get:

```
    Checker Iteration: 0
    Checker Iteration: 1
    Checker Iteration: 2
    ...
    ...
    Checker Iteration: 29
    Task exception was never retrieved
    future: <Task finished name='Task-3' coro=<foo() done, defined at C:\Users\Sri         Vedurumudi\code\speedtest\speedtest.py:8> exception=TypeError("'Process' object is not callable")>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Sri Vedurumudi\code\speedtest\speedtest.py", line 12, in foo
        await asyncio.gather(asyncio.to_thread(proc))
      File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\threads.py", line 25, in to_thread
        return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func_call)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    TypeError: 'Process' object is not callable
```

Can a Python (using 3.9.4) expert point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are several issues. Start with a simple coroutine that just succesfully runs the "speedtest" external program. Add multiple tasks in next step.

Comment: Thanks @VPfB, I just posted what worked for me. Can you suggest any issues with that approach? Obviously I'm not handling exceptions or introduced timeouts to control rogue processes.

Comment: I did not run it, but it looks good. I'd like to suggest `asyncio.run(main())` as a simpler way to start your program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what seems to be working. But, if you spot any issues with the code, please let me know. I'm posting this mainly for future reference or for anyone in a similar situation. Obviously, I am not handling errors or introduce a timeout to check rogue executables.

```
import asyncio

async def checker():
    for i in range(40):
        print(f'Checker Iteration: {i}')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def foo():
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec("speedtest", stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    # Wait for the process to complete
    await proc.wait()   
    # Read the output
    output = await proc.stdout.read(-1)
    print(f'Process Return Code: {proc.returncode} and Output: \n{output}')


async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(checker())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(foo())

    await asyncio.gather(t2,t1)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```